# Authenticate against OAuth provider (Shopify) without using browser from server code

Tags: asp.net, server, oauth, access-token

So, I have an ASP.Net Shopify app which pulls information (orders) from Shopify.

My goal is to have it to display the order data *without* having to redirect the browser to Shopify for authentication. Instead I want the server side code store the password and create the authentication tokens and "behind the scenes" talk to Shopify, and I guess, act as the browser would have.

(Would I need something [like this "grant" library](https://github.com/simov/grant), but for .NET instead of NodeJS?)

The code currently gets tokens like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromQuery] string shop = "somehostname.myshopify.com")
    {
        var requiredPermissions = new [] { "read_orders", "read_products" };
        var oauthState = await _dataContext.States.AddAsync(new OauthState
        {
            DateCreated = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            Token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        });

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        var oauthUrl = AuthorizationService.BuildAuthorizationUrl(
            requiredPermissions,
            shop,
            _secrets.ShopifyApiKey,
            _oauthRedirectUrl,
            oauthState.Entity.Token);

        return Redirect(oauthUrl.ToString());
    }
```

This is the code which sets up AspNetCore authentication builder:

```
private static void ConfigureCookieAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/Login";
    }


     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(ConfigureCookieAuthentication);
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        // Add the database context which injects the context into each controller's constructor
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(GetSqlConnectionString()));
        // Add ISecrets so classes can use the Shopify secret/api keys
        services.AddSingleton<ISecrets, Secrets>();
    }
```

But none of this really helps, does it? Would I need to have the server side pretend to be a desktop browser and login to the login form like a human user would have, or is there some mechanism in OAuth itself which would let me do what I want?

Any ideas on how to make the server side do the login itself against Shopify (or whatever OAuth server) instead of the browser?

Comment: I suppose this is related somehow but it's going over my head: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072374/programmatic-authentication-with-oauth2